# Navigate to NotFound page if http GetById returns 404

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side

Suppose I have the following Routing schema

- **CustomerListComponent**: Containing a list of Customers
- **CustomerDetailComponent**: Holding the details of a specific customer

with Routes

- @page "customer"
- @page "customer/{id:int}

and a Router setup as such:

```
<Router AppAssembly="typeof(Startup).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        ....
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
    </NotFound>
</Router>
```

I want the page to redirect to the `NotFound` page, if the `http` call does **not** find the customer with the id that was passed to the `URL`

Inside my component right now

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
   var customer = await CustomerService.GetById(customerId);
   if (customer == null) 
   {
      // redirect to 404 NOTFOUND         
   }
}
```

It seems that right now, any valid integer in the URL will open the CustomerDetail component and when it tries to show the Customer details, it will (obviously) crash with a `null reference`

Am I missing something obvious?

**EDIT :** I have tried to load a custom 404 page and handle navigation inside my http service, but this results in URL change on the browser. I want to preserve the faulty URL and still navigate to the 404 page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `NavigationManager`

```cs
@inject NavigationManager _nagigationManager;
...
@code {
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
       var customer = await CustomerService.GetById(customerId);
       if (customer == null) 
       {
          _navigationManager.NavigateTo("404page");
       }
   }
}
```

If you want to stay on the same page, but display the content of an error page, just add the component in your html code :

```cs
@if(_notFound) 
{
    <NotFoundPage />
}
else
{
...
}
@code {
    private bool _notFound;
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
       var customer = await CustomerService.GetById(customerId);
       if (customer == null) 
       {
          _notFound = true;
          StateHasChanged();
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Does this preserve the faulty url that instigated the 404 on the browser? I want to avoid losing information by changing the url to ".../my-not-found-page/"

Comment: you can path the faulty url in query string

Comment: I'll upvote but this leads to weird behaviour. For instance, if my @page has an int restriction like so path "customer/{id: int} this will go through this code for wrong Ids, but it will go through the standard not found section, if the passed Id is larger than an int32. I'd rather have it handled at a single place, rather than two different ones.

Comment: @IoannisStefanou On WASM or server ?